# Renomear anexos antes de salvar

Tags: vba, outlook

Senhores, tenho o seguinte problema.
Toda segunda feira, recebo de um sistema 12 e-mails, sendo eles:

SEXTA:

- MIPS_1
- MIPS_2
- MIPS_3
- MIPS_4

SABADO:

- MIPS_1
- MIPS_2
- MIPS_3
- MIPS_4

DOMINGO:

- MIPS_1
- MIPS_2
- MIPS_3
- MIPS_4

E preciso de um jeito em que eu salve esses arquivos em um diretório do computador, renomeando eles para que não substitua o arquivo atual.
Em algumas pesquisas, eu consegui o seguinte código:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String
Dim f As Long
Dim NewName


'f = f + 1


' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\brunoco\Desktop\Teste Macro MIPS"
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\brunoco\Desktop\Teste Macro MIPS\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then

        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.

        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
           For Each objAttachments In objMsg
            f = f + 1


            'If strSubject.Contains("VIDE") Then
            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            'strFile = Left(objAttachments.Item(i).Filename, Len(objAttachments.Item(i).Filename) - 4) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Day(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Month(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("0000" + Trim(Str$(Year(Now))), 4) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Hour(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Minute(Now))), 2) + "_" + Right("00" + Trim(Str$(Second(Now))), 2) + Right((objAttachments.Item(i).Filename), 4)
            strFile = Left(objAttachments.Item(i).Filename, Len(objAttachments.Item(i).Filename) - 4) + "_" + Right((strSubject), 2) + Right((objAttachments.Item(i).Filename), 4)


            'If strSubject.Contains("VIDE") Then
            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile


            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

            ' Delete the attachment.
            'objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

            'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
            'check for html and use html tags in link
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
            Else
                strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
            End If

            'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
            'MsgBox strDeletedFiles
          Next


        Next i

        ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
        ' Check for HTML body
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
        Else
            objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
        End If
        objMsg.Save
    End If
Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Ele faz corretamente para o 1 primeiro dia, porem nos seguintes, ele substitui o arquivo, invalidando o que preciso fazer.
Gostaria de renomear para a seguinte forma:

SEXTA:

- MIPS_1_SEX
- MIPS_2_SEX
- MIPS_3_SEX
- MIPS_4_SEX

SABADO:

- MIPS_1_SAB
- MIPS_2_SAB
- MIPS_3_SAB
- MIPS_4_SAB

DOMINGO:

- MIPS_1_DOM
- MIPS_2_DOM
- MIPS_3_DOM
- MIPS_4_DOM

Agradeço a ajuda desde já!!!

Comment: Ele ja esta usando o .SaveAs

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código para realizar esta manipulação de string:

```
arquivo = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
nome_arquivo = fso.GetBaseName(arquivo)
extensao_arquivo = Replace(arquivo, nome_arquivo, "")
                    
If arquivo Like ("*MIPS_*") Then
    If j = 3 Then
        k = k + 1
        j = 0
    End If
    strFile = nome_arquivo & "_" & arr(k) & extensao_arquivo
    j = j + 1

Else
    'strFile = arquivo
End If
```

Se o anexo conter a palavra `MIPS_` cria os arquivos na ordem, caso contrário salva somente o nome do arquivo em anexo.

#### Explicação

- `arquivo = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName` é o nome do anexo, por exemplo: "Nome_Do_Arquivo.txt"
- `nome_arquivo = fso.GetBaseName(arquivo)` é o nome do arquivo sem a extensão, ex.: "Nome_Do_Arquivo"
- `extensao_arquivo = Replace(arquivo, nome_arquivo, "")` é a extensão do arquivo, ex.: ".txt"
- `strFile = nome_arquivo & "_" & arr(k) & extensao_arquivo` concatena o nome final do arquivo que será salvo, com algum valor do vetor `arr`. O índice `k` do vetor é incrementado toda vez que 4 MIPS_ são salvos.

#### Código

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem               'Object
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
    Dim f As Long
    Dim NewName
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim j As Long, k As Long
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


    ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
    'strFolderpath = "C:\Users\brunoco\Desktop\Teste Macro MIPS\"
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    ' Set the Attachment folder.
    strFolderpath = "C:\Users\brunoco\Desktop\Teste Macro MIPS\"

    ' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
    ' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
    For Each objMsg In objSelection

        ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
        ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
        ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
        Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        strDeletedFiles = ""

        If lngCount > 0 Then

            ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
            ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
            ' confused and only every other item is removed.

            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
                k = 0
                arr = Array("SEX", "SAB", "DOM")
                For Each objAttachments In objMsg
                    f = f + 1
                   
                    arquivo = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
                    nome_arquivo = fso.GetBaseName(arquivo)
                    extensao_arquivo = Replace(arquivo, nome_arquivo, "")
                    
                    If arquivo Like ("*MIPS_*") Then
                        If j = 3 Then
                            k = k + 1
                            j = 0
                        End If
                        strFile = nome_arquivo & "_" & arr(k) & extensao_arquivo
                        j = j + 1

                    Else
                        strFile = arquivo
                    End If


                    'If strSubject.Contains("VIDE") Then
                    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
                    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile


                    ' Save the attachment as a file.
                    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

                    ' Delete the attachment.
                    'objAttachments.Item(i).Delete

                    'write the save as path to a string to add to the message
                    'check for html and use html tags in link
                    If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                        strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile & ">"
                    Else
                        strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & _
                                          strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
                    End If

                    'Use the MsgBox command to troubleshoot. Remove it from the final code.
                    'MsgBox strDeletedFiles
                Next


            Next i

            ' Adds the filename string to the message body and save it
            ' Check for HTML body
            If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
                objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
            Else
                objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
            End If
            objMsg.Save
        End If
    Next

ExitSub:

    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Daniel, fiz o teste, mas ele acaba pegando os arquivos adiciona o _SEX e quando pega os outros dias, simplesmente substitui o arquivo, nao cria outros 8 com o _SAB e _DOM

Comment: @BrunoCovre Veja o edit

Comment: fiz as alterações no codigo, e agora ele salva 3 com _SEX e um com _SAB.
O nome do arquivo é esse : MIPS_SECP.txt , MIPS_SECD.txt , MIPS_VIDE.TXT e MIPS_ELO1.TXT.
Não sei se ajuda.

Comment: Veja como foi realizado esta manipulação de Strings, há outras maneiras de manipular também. Com isso você conseguirá realizar um código com base na concatenação realizada de exemplo.